# Tying Devices to Azure AD & Bit Locker Recovery

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-active-directory, bitlocker

We want our users to be able to join their machine to Azure AD and encrypt with their credentials thereby storing the bitlocker recovery key under their user record in azure 
How can we accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you connect a computer or device to Azure AD it is automatically encrypted using Bitlocker and the encryption key is stored in Azure AD.
There are however requirements for this to happen.
**The Device must be a InstantGo capable device.**

These are devices that can "go to sleep" but still receive notifications in background such as E-mail, SMS...

To check if the device is compatible open a command prompt and type:

```
powercfg /a
```

Devices that have InstantGo support will return “Network Connected"